# Getting error if trying to use Javascript standard method isNan in LWC javascript file

Tags: lightning-web-components

Getting error if trying to validate the number value by using isNan() method of Javascript. Debugged chrome browser tool and get message 'isNan is not defined'.
Do I need to import something to make it usable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language. The method is called [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN).

Comment: Thanks @David. I knew JS is case-sensitive but somehow it skipped.